# Python Multiple Simultaneous and Communicating Scripts

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a project which will run on Raspberry Pi 4 and I have decided to use Python for scripting. I have several sensors, a camera, a screen etc.. I have written couple of scripts and I know that I can run them simultaneously by adding `&` at the end of the `python3 <script.name>` command on terminal. However, my question is this:

For example I have 2 scripts, scriptA and scriptB and both of these scripts should do something according to the other script. Let's say in scriptA I use a sensor, and when it detects something I want scriptB to do something different than usually what it does. How can I do that, how can I make these two scripts communicate in best way? I know Thumb2 assembly and interrupts, and C/C++. However, I am very new to Python. My project is not very time-critical, so I think that I do not need to use interrupts, but I do not know how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution would be to create different classes for each process that can pass information back and fourth more efficiently, but if you are hell bent on using different scripts, you can use the `os.system()` call and pass in different arguments which tells the script to do something different.

For example, script_a.py calls script_b.py passing an argument to script_b.py:

script_a.py:

```
import os

state_change = True

if state_change:
    os.system("script_b.py 1") # you can replace 1 with any character you want
else:
    os.system("script_b.py 0")
```

In script_b.py, you would parse the passed in arguments and execute a corresponding action:

```
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == '1':
    do_something()
elif sys.argv[1] == '0':
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By saying different classes for each processes, you mean single script, right? Isn't having separate scripts for different processes a better way to organize things? I want to hear your opinion. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I mean a single script. By single script, I don't mean a single file. A single script can include multiple files (usually your classes and modules). For example you can create a Camera class and Screen class and run both of them in your main.py program. It's also easier to pass information back and fourth between classes. If you are writing a single program, using classes to encapsulate your different processes is the way to go.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. One last question, for the way you mentioned, how can I run each different processes (classes) simultaneously in a single script?

Comment: So you would create different classes for your different processes, and then import them in your main script `import ClassName`, and then create an instance of each one `camera = Camera()` and `screen = Screen()`. Then from there you can call your classes methods. ex. `camera.take_picture()`